# Stretch button with unstretchable central region

Tags: android, button, nine-patch, stretch

Is there any way to stretch the button so that the central part remained intact? 9-patch doesn't allow to do this.
[image]

**EDIT:** I used 9-patch as Benito recommended. And it works fine. It is strange that the first time I couldn't get it.
[image]

Comment: 9-patch tool allow this, you can select region for stretch, have a good tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like the image below

[image: 9-patch image]

But make sure you make the background transparent.